# Double integral over a line segment?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$Q(C) = \int\int_C f(x,y)dxdy$
If $C$ is a line segment of finite length in the $xy$ plane won't $Q(C)=0$?

Normally $C$ is a region with non-zero area. This question has me confused since it seems like everything is being multiplied by $0$.

My other idea is to interpret $Q(C)$ as a line integral. But that seems fundamentally wrong.

Comment: If $\;C\;$ is a line segment then that seems to be a line integral...why then the double integral symbol?

Comment: That is how Q(C) is *defined* so I think making it into a line integral is changing the nature of the question. It wants a volume in xy, yes?

Comment: The *usual* interpretation would be the volume of the three dimensional body enclosed between the area on the $\;xy\,-$ plane and the surface $\;f(x,y)\;$ above (or below) it. If we stick to this then yes: the **volume** is zero...

Comment: How can $C$ be one-dimensional while the integral measure $dxdy$ is two-dimensional? I'm not saying it's impossible; if this is actually what you mean then yes this quantity is automatically zero. But....... you sure this is what you want?

Comment: It seems to me that the question as you stumbled upon it is very  badly posed. It just doesn't make sense to talk about two  measures in the context of a line integral. it's also possible that the author mistakenly said line integral when he meant area or surface integral.

Comment: The set C was defined C={(x,y): 0<x=y<1 } I take that to be a diagonal line segment with the endpoints missing from (0,0) to (1,1)

Comment: I want to add that previously C was a rectangular region such as C={(x,y): -3<x<1, 0<y<1 } that made total sense.